# Cut a shape on another one

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to recreate this kind of image focusing on the white shapes on the blue planet.

I tried to create rounded rectangles in Adobe Illustrator and then use the scissor tool but the result is not the same.

I would like that the the white shapes fits perfectly on the circle edge like in this image.

How can I do that?

[image: The planet with white shapes on it I'd like to recreate]

Answer (score 4):

You could use a clipping mask for this.  This is what I would recommend as it's non-destructive, and you can still move the clouds around inside the circle afterwards if you want to rearrange them.

Let's say you have a circle, and cloud shapes above it

1. Select the circle and copy it
2. Select everything and group
3. Do *Edit > Paste in Front* to paste a copy of the circle on top of the group
4. Select everything and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, or do *Ojbect > Clipping Mask > Make*

An example

[image]

If instead you want to physically cut away the pieces that overlap the circle, you could use the Shape Builder tool.

Holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> as you click (or click and drag) using the Shape Builder tool will delete the pieces.

[image]

Another possibility for removing the physical overlap

1. Select the all the cloud pieces, and combine them using *Object > Compound Path > Make*
2. Copy the circle
3. Select everything, and in the Shape Builder, hit "Intersect". This boolean operation will consume the circle.
4. Do *Edit > Paste in Back* to paste the circle back, under the clouds.

It would also be possible to use a Divide boolean operation similar to the above, but then you would have to remove the parts outside the circle by manually selecting and deleting them.